# Postgresql command pg_update fails going from version 14 to 15

Tags: postgresql

I run a command that seems like it should work. Both the old bin and new bin dirs contain correct postgres versions. But the command fails as if this is reversed. What? Am? I? doing wrong?

```
pg_upgrade --old-bindir /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/14.9/bin/ \
             --new-bindir /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@15/15.4/bin/ \
             --old-datadir /usr/local/var/postgres.14.9.backup \
             --new-datadir /usr/local/var/postgres \
```

> check for "/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@15/15.4/bin/postgres" failed:
> incorrect version: found "postgres (PostgreSQL) 15.4 (Homebrew)",
> expected "postgres (PostgreSQL) 14.9 (Homebrew)" Failure, exiting

I tried the new pg_upgrade binary and that resulted in

```
-----------------------------
Checking cluster versions
This utility can only upgrade to PostgreSQL version 15.
Failure, exiting
```

Comment: Which version of `pg_upgrade` are you using? Run `pg_upgrade -V` to verify. I'm betting you are using the 14 version.

Comment: I exchanged the old command for the newer one, and now I get a message that clusters versions can only upgrade to version 15, which is the one I want and have installed.

Comment: 1) It might be easier to just do a dump/restore upgrade. 2) Is there a initialized 15 cluster in  `/usr/local/var/postgres`?

Comment: It is the same as the old one.. ie) version 14

Comment: Then that is not going work. You need a fresh `initdb` of a 15 cluster to upgrade to. I would highly recommend reading the *Usage* section here [pg_upgrade](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgupgrade.html). It runs through the upgrade process step by step.

Comment: I ran a fresh initdb (version 15 of command) on the /usr/local/var/postgres directory but get the same error

Comment: I doubt the `initdb` actually ran as it will bail if the directory already has files in it

Comment: I started with an empty directory and the version file PG_VERSION sits as 15

Comment: I have been using PG since version 6 I think and never have I ever had it be so damned hard to just move from A to B!!! I am thinking Homebrew and MacOS are to blame

Comment: Expand your cross checks.  Instead of just looking in /usr/local/var/postgre/PG_VERSION, actually start the new cluster with the new binaries and log into it and look around, call `select version()`.  Just don't create any objects.  This should not be necessary, but it could point up any problems.

Comment: Did a psql restore with the dumpall file and that at least worked... so much for pg_upgrade! Nothing but trouble with that!

Comment: Your edit indicates that `/usr/local/var/postgres` was *not* created with PostgreSQL v15. You only can blame yourself for that.

Answer (score 1):

The pg_upgrade binary you call (which is found from your PATH in your example) needs to be the one from the new version, not from the old version.

Either fix your PATH, or give the absolute path to the pg_upgrade executable:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@15/15.4/bin/pg_upgrade ...
```

Comment: Tried that, but then the result is

Performing Consistency Checks
-----------------------------
Checking cluster versions
This utility can only upgrade to PostgreSQL version 15.
Failure, exiting

Comment: Ok, so now you have a different problem.